# Kendo UI autocomplete from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete, kendo-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using asp.net mvc 4 and i have few textboxes which needs to be filled if the record exist in the database i need something like autocomplete textbox so that when i enter the value on the textbox it will fill other textboxes if the record is in the database is there any tutorial or someone has already implemented this feature please help me out i tried to search on google but i could not find any example.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the ComboBox?  http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html